# QGIS 3 batch processing - INPUT value not correct when autofill

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, expression, string, batch

I want to batch process with Clip function (also problem with any other). I have several input layers. I would like to autofill the output `Clipped` parameter with name of the input feature and `_clipped` suffix, such as in this example:

[image]

The Expression String Builder acts oddly when I use `@INPUT` parameter, there is a name of the input feature along with some weird memory address or something.

[image]

Why does this happen with the INPUT layer name? Where do I find the name without the odd suffix?

---

I found out I can go around this when I tinker with the string a bit like so:

`string_to_array(@INPUT,'_')[0]`

Then I get:

[image]

However, what if the name itself contain underscores?

Comment: If you use OUTPUT instead will that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That weird string is not a memory address, but the layer's id. You can use the following expression to construct `INPUTLAYERNAME_clipped` string. And no need `string_to_array(@INPUT,'_')[0]`.

```
layer_property( @INPUT, 'name' ) + '_clipped'
```

`layer_property(@INPUT, 'name')`  returns the layer name. If you need the layer source file name, use this:

```
base_file_name( layer_property( @INPUT, 'source' ) ) + '_clipped'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good workaround a partly offers a solution. I wrote it earlier here as a Q&A style but it was deleted by the moderator as apparently a new question... Nevertheless, how comes that you don't get to acquire base file name in the query builder?

Comment: @janchytry Do you need the input file name instead of layer name?

Comment: Not exactly in this case, but often I do.

Comment: @janchytry I see, I've added how to get file name.

Comment: Thanks, that's an nice combination of functions I haven't known about.